Salesforce Inspector crashing when copying large results
When trying to copy the results of a query (excel, csv, or JSON format), Chrome will crash completely. The query itself will complete successfully, only when copying will the browser crash. This is happening to a subset of our users and started happening a couple of months ago.
Some of our end users rely on Salesforce Inspector for some data validation, daily checks, ad-hoc requests, etc. These users do not have access to Developer Console or data loader and our company has a strict process to provision new add-ins (so we currently can't explore other add-in options). Any idea if there's a setting or config that could resolve this issue?
Sample query:
SELECT ID, Name, AccountId, Account.Name, Email, Phone, RecordType.Name, RecordType.Id, CreatedDate, CreatedBy.Name, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedBy.Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1500


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Are you using the newer extension version?  Regardless, you'll need to contact the vendor for this extension issue.

Try XL-Connector 365, you'll get your data directly to Excel without the need to copy-paste.
